# Is log^2 (n) ∈ O(n) true?

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics

I'm new to algorithm, and I am already overwhelmed with the term ∈ I really could use some good explanation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_(mathematics)

Comment: $O(n)=\{f\mid f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^+}\land \exists n_0\in \mathbb{N}:\exists c>0: \forall n > n_0: f(n) \le c \cdot n\}$

Comment: This will take awhile to learn, but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For your question in the title,$\ log(n)\in O(n)$ is true.

For what you seem to actually be looking for. The the "is element of" relation, denoted by $\in$, is not specific to algorithms and complexity theory, but is a concept from set theory that is used everywhere throughout pure and applied mathematics. Where$\ O(n)$ is a "set" of functions, the statement$\ log(n)\in O(n)$ is saying that $\ log(n)$ is one of the functions in this set.

For a great introduction to these concepts I would highly suggest *How to Prove It* by Daniel J Velleman for learning about set theory and then *Introduction to the Theory of Computation* by Michael Sipser to learn more about how these concepts are applied to the theory of computation.

Comment: Question is about $\log^2 n \in O(n)$, which is also true. Most easy way as far, as I know, is using L'Hopital rule.

Answer (score 0):

Yes $(log(n))^k \in O(n)$ for any positive fixed $k$.
In fact, for any fixed positive small $c$, you further have that $(log(n))^k \in O(n^c)$ for every fixed $k$. So even $(log(n))^{100} \in O(\sqrt{n})$, for example.

Comment: Although you need some really large n to make say (log n)^100 nanoseconds less than sqrt(n) nanoseconds. More than 2^2200 (> 2^1100 vs 2^1100).

Comment: Yes @gnasher729 this is the point of big-O .... it is a statement about growth rates as $n\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: But it defeats the point where you say “use an algorithm with lower asymptotic complexity). If the crossover point is beyond the lifetime of the universe.

Comment: Big Oh is a coarse classification for sure. The point you make about some problems shifting a constant so high up it becomes impracticable is valid. The same issues hold for many other concepts. Turing computability results (speed up theorem) for one, and other applications. The maths is useful to support insight. After that, the decision is whether that insight is useful in practice.

Comment: I think you should add proof of the statement in your answer.

Comment: The proof follows readily from l'hospital's rule